# Websockets behind Apache and Nginx proxy connection not upgraded

Tags: apache, nginx, proxy, websocket

I have a problem. Apache listens on a white ip and proxies all requests /ssd on nginx that proxies requests /city-dashboard to another server with websockets. In apache config:

```
ProxyPass /ssd/ http://10.127.32.24
ProxyPassReverse /ssd/ http://10.127.32.24
```

nginx config:
on nginx.conf:

```
 map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

on default.conf

```
 location /city-dashboard/stream {
     proxy_pass http://10.127.32.24:5000/stream;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
 }
```

Request headers:

```
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: Websocket
```

Response headers:

```
Connection: close
Status Code 400 Bad Request
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you set up mod_websocket?

Comment: In latest version of apache (2.4.6+) exist wstunnel module, I'm added it through LoadModule in my .conf  file

Answer (score 0):

What about authorization header in request ? it seems authorization problem.

Comment: Can you check connection and upgrade header values? these shoulde be upgrade for connection header and websocket for upgrade header.

Comment: In request it's true, but in response is not present these headers

Comment: these are sufficient for handshake request. can you put more info about request here? it might be corrupted headers or payload but payload is not required to websocket handshake.

Comment: It's request:`GET ws://x.x.x.x/ssd/city-dashboard/stream HTTP/1.1
Host: x.x.x.x
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: http://x.x.x.x
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 881o9c/z3Q437JFCti3BIw==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits`

Comment: It's response: `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Thu, 30 Jul 2015 20:46:15 GMT
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 54
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Via: 1.1 app-test.localdomain
Connection: close`

Comment: i tried this, but result is the same `Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400`

Comment: No, through 2 or more proxies websockets are couldn't to run